# Alternative to document.write javascript?

Tags: javascript

I had a working alternative I think.... I believe I erased it now I can not find it. Does anybody know an alternative to document.write javascript? Here is the code:

```
document.write('<div id="myDiv1"></div>');
```

Does anybody know an alternative to document.write javascript?

Comment: Alternative to achieve what goal? `document.write` is pretty specific in what it does.

Comment: yea but when I use ajax to load a body the document.write loads instead...

Comment: So at some point you want to add a new `div` to the DOM via JavaScript, but it may run after the DOM has loaded. In that case, you have a very large and well documented DOM API at your disposal, not to mention many, many library APIs that can be used if you desire.

Comment: The alternative is to use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM)

Comment: I was just looking for something lighter....document.write works...but it does not work well.

Comment: You can't really replicate what document.write() does directly because you have to know *where* you want the div to be placed. with document.write, it's placed in the dom where the script that executed it is located if the dom is still open, otherwise it replaces the page with the content.

Comment: @user3499262: It works great for what it's intended to do. I think you just need to read a simple tutorial or two on DOM manipulation. This is well-covered territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [document.create<...>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)?

```
 var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
 var newContent = document.createTextNode("Whateveryourcontentis");
 newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
 document.querySelector("#mytarget").appendChild(newDiv)
```

Alternatively if you have to enter a more complex structure I would use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

Answer (score 0):

The `document.create<...>` solution is the safest, but if you need to insert raw HTML stored as a string (from a trusted source only, e.g., do not use this method with content posted by other users, even if modern browsers are disallowing), you can use `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<b>I can add raw markup!<\/b><img src="x" onerror=\'alert("But be careful!")\'>';
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML to understand more on the ongoing risks of using `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` with untrusted content. It is basically as dangerous as using `eval()` with untrusted content.